# Check if a given Type is an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I am writing a JsonConverter for Json.NET which should allow me to convert any enum's to a string value defined by a [Description] attribute.

For example:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    [Description("Sunday")] Sunday,
    [Description("Monday")] Monday,
    [Description("Tuesday")] Tuesday,
    [Description("Wednesday")] Wednesday,
    [Description("Thursday")] Thursday,
    [Description("Friday")] Friday,
    [Description("Saturday")] Saturday
}
```

I already have the code for supporting `myEnum.Description()` which will obviously return its string description.

In the JsonConverter implementation, there is this method:

```
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {

    }
```

I am trying to figure out how to determine if `objectType` is an `Enum` and return true so that the converter knows it can convert this object.  Since I have many `Enum`'s, I cannot explicitly check each one so I was hoping for a more generic way of accomplishing this.

Comment: When you say "determine if objectType is an Enum", you basically want to check if the objectType is "MyEnum", rather than just any other enum. Is that correct?

Comment: No I want to check if it is any Enum. @minitech's answer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Use the [`IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) property:

```
if(objectType.IsEnum) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: or just `return objectType.IsEnum`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: I figured that since the method is called `CanConvert`, it will check for multiple different possible conversions, not just if it's an `enum`. Otherwise you may as well just use the `IsEnum` property itself.

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi: You're very welcome :) Make sure to always browse the IntelliSense, I've learned a lot from it.

Comment: @SergeyMetlov in PCL you can use objectType.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum

Comment: how bout if (myObject is Enum)

Comment: @NickKovalsky: Why bother with RTTI when there’s an actual property?

Comment: Additional information if you are using reflection: use the <PropertyInfo>.PropertyType.IsEnum rather than <PropertyInfo>.GetType().IsEnum.

Answer (score 27):

[Type.IsEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) is what your are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I completely misinterpreted the question by focusing too much on the [Description], so in case you ever want to check whether a particular enum has a [description] attribute or not ( in case json throws a fit when there is none ), this is one possible way to check for that:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    if( fieldInfo.Length > 0 )
    {
        return ( fieldInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),false).Length > 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```